# Publish a netcore/netstandard library

Tags: .net-core, csproj

I have a library referencing some nugets, which i wish to publish with all the dependencies. But when I do that via the publish command in VS, the output dir contains the nupkg file, instead the binaries. I've found that I can use `CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies` to include the dependencies in build, but I have a feeling that this might be wrong.

So my question is, whether using the `CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies` property is the correct way to publish a library and if it isn't what is?

Comment: Does `dotnet publish` generate the right output for you?

Comment: No, gives the same results.